# ObservableCollection crashes UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Ive been dealing with a UWP app that it has issues when loading/rendering a new view that has a few 80+ of items in the ListView. I have to display a lot of columns(properties of each item in the listView). I read about virtualization but I'm not sure if that's the right approach in this case (seems more appropriate for a larger set of data). The app crashes without any stack trace or anything that can be helpful

In the viewModel all that I do is `Items = new ObservableCollection<ListModel>(products)`
This is my xaml code:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      Grid.Row="1">
            <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Name="NewItemView"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Margin="0,0,0,0"
                      Background="White"
                      Width="{Binding Path=GridWidth, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <GridView.Header>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0"
                          Background="#FF6FC3E8"
                          BorderBrush="White"
                          BorderThickness="1">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                   x:Uid="dataVerifiedSubt"
                                   Width="150"
                                   Style="{StaticResource TextBlockTitleProductsListPage}"
                                   x:Name="dataVerified"></TextBlock>
                        <ListView Grid.Column="1"
                                  Height="100"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                  RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="dataVerified"
                                  SelectionMode="None"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProductFields, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  IsItemClickEnabled="True">
                            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductField.Field_Name}"
                                               Width="150"
                                               Style="{StaticResource TextBlockTitleProductsListPage}"></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemClick">
                                    <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=test}">
                                    </core:InvokeCommandAction>
                                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        </ListView>
                    </Grid>
                </GridView.Header>
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding test1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                            <ListView Grid.Column="1"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding ProductFieldValues, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                      Width="{Binding Width,ElementName=NewItemView}"
                                      SelectionMode="None"
                                      Style="{StaticResource ProductListTable}"
                                      Name="ProductFieldValuesList">
                                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OpenProductInfo, ElementName=NewItemView}"
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext.ProductId, ElementName=ProductFieldValuesList}"
                                                Style="{StaticResource ProductListPageTextBlockButton}">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                        </Button>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListView>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

I get this after the crash:

[image]

thanks

Comment: What is the error/exception?

Comment: theres no exception, even if I had the observableCollection assignment wrapped in a try and catch. This is what I get on the console 
The thread 0x57b0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[15992]  has exited with code -1073741189 (0xc000027b).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From you XAML:

- Your GridView won't benefit from virtualization because you have it inside a scrollviewer which will allow it to grow vertically to display/load all items. Your GridView will automatically show scrollbars when there are too many items to fit in the viewport.

I have had this issue a while back which was because virtualization not working since the listview i was using was allowed to stretch vertically off the page bounds forcing it to load all items (400+ at that time) which caused the app to crash with a similar "Attach debugger" dialog. So first thing I'd try it to move your GridView outside of the ScrollViewer so that Virtualization can kick in.

- In the GridView Header, you have a listview that is attempting to set its location with `RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="dataVerified"` which doesn't look right because you don't have a relative panel in there.
- One last thing I'd check to see which thread is initializing and setting that ObservableCollection. If it is happening on a different thread then the app will crash because you can't set UI properties from a non-UI thread. Since you are loading products from some source, it is most likely you are doing it in an async void/task so make sure you are marshalling that call (initializing the collection and setting the property) back to the UI thread. I am not sure if this thing will cause a Win32 exception but it is something worth checking.
- Also, this is not related to the problem, but you don't need `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in your bindings.

Comment: thanks @Rafael. The scrollviewer was messing with the virtualization and did the trick.

Comment: Although it is old, but it help me a lot. When I change ObservableCollection to normal list my problem disappear. But I am not sure how we can marshall changes. as if I add item or change value of Item, in my Async function I did there ..